# rails generate migration : no more version number - acts_as_archive compatibility?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, version

When I do a:

```
rails generate migration xxx
```

I get : ... create db/migrate/_xxx.rb

No timestamp and not any kind of numbering.

I tried:

```
rake db:migrate:reset -> no change  
rake db:version -> correct value (20120509143011)  
add config.active_record.timestamped_migration=false -> same problem (so i removed this line)
```

I'm using rails 3.2 - ruby 1.9.2 - rvm - mysql

Any idea?

Comment: try config.active_record.timestamped_migration=true

Comment: I tried ... no change. Do you know where the numbering is generated ?

Comment: Thanks for posting your resolution. I suggest adding the offending gem name to the title or the text of the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem corrected ... but i'm not sure why ;-(

The last thing i did was to remove the gem "act_as_archive". then i generated a migration to remove the corresponding table and, my timestamp were back !

I did this 2 or 3 times (adding/removing the gem), and the problem is reproductible (in my project at least)

So I suppose this is a compatibility problem with acts_as_archive gem.
I hope this will help others.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the version of the 'also_migrate' gem that the acts_as_archive uses (0.35). The next version (0.36) fixes the problem. If memory serves I believe the method_missing alias was not returning a value from whatever operation it performed